# How to use Katalon Studio custom keyword

Tags: database, katalon-studio

How can I use this custom keyword?

```
com.katalon.plugin.keyword.connection.DatabaseKeywords.executeQuery
```

Please note that I installed it from the Katalon store:

https://store.katalon.com/product/24/DBMS-Custom-Keywords

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
CustomKeywords.'com.katalon.plugin.keyword.connection.DatabaseKeywords.executeQuery'("query string")
```

?

or

```
import com.katalon.plugin.keyword.connection.DatabaseKeywords as DK

DK.executeQuery("query string")
```

Comment: this custom key have to parameters connection and query, but I don't know how to populate connection parameter right if you know the right format please help me.

Comment: `variable` should be of type java.sql.Connection

Comment: how can I do this, please?

Comment: It depends on your database, but generally should consist of a db URL, username and password. See some examples [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/java.sql.Connection) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm).

Comment: Hello, are you trying to create a database connector ?